# Unable to display Cyrillic symbols in curses

Tags: python, windows, windows-7, python-2.6

I've decided to go with cp866 to avoid unicode 65001 nightmare(bug, patches, etc... please), so each output string in my program is encoded into cp866

```
# coding=utf-8
print 'Кабздец'.decode('utf-8').encode('cp866')
```

this line output correct string into windows console, of course if I set chcp 866 prior running my script.

However, I am not able to make curses to display in same encoding.

```
stdscr.addstr("Кабздец".decode('utf-8').encode('cp866'))
```

This will output garbage. Curses doc says that I have to set locale. So I tried to use

```
locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, '')
```

This has little change and still garbage, I guess because my locale is CP1251. `locale.getpreferredencoding()` returns `cp1251`.

Question is how to make curses to encode strings correctly.

I've also tried

```
locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, 'rus')
```

which will just render different symbols, not correct ones.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried playing around with the altcharacterset attribute on the addstr call yet?

Comment: nm, that doesn't look to be it... this is a tricky problem.  Have you tried just using the method they have in the examples in the docs and just using the default encoding after setting the locale?

Comment: I found some solution by setting locale in program to `rus`, changing codepage from 866 to 1251 in both console using chcp and in program. I guess this is the best I can achieve.